# THREE.JS: Как передать массив в шейдер как униформу

Tags: массивы, float, three.js, glsl

Что-то не могу найти работующего примера как передать массив чисел в GLSL как uniform.

```
var array = new Float32Array(6);
for(var i = 0; i < 6; i++){ array[i] = Math.random(); }

var uniform = {

params: { value: array }

};
```

и в самом шейдере (fragment)

```
uniform float params;
или uniform float[] params;
или uniform float params[6];
```

все варианты не работают, первые два выдают ошибку, третий 0.0.

```
var uniforms = {

params: { type: "fv", value: [0.1, 0.6, 0.4] }

};
```

тоже не работает

Answer (score 0):

Методом подбора пришёл к работающей схеме:

```
var uniform = {

params: { type: "fv1", value: [0.1, 0.75, 0.95] } 

}
```

в шейдере

```
uniform float params[3];
```

Comment: `type` уже можно не добавлять для униформ.